# Tar exploded permissions are difefrent

Tags: 20.04, permissions, tar

Downloaded open JDK tar.gz file from https://jdk.java.net/15/. When I expand this file with command tar -xf openjdk-15.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz  on one box permissions look like

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me 4.0K Feb 17 15:57 bin
```

On the other hand when same file, copied to other box and expanded with same command

```
drwxr-x---  2 me me 4.0K Feb 17 16:37 bin
```

Same applies to other files in bin directory - no one except myself who expanded the file has execute permissions. As a result I am not able to execute any of the java commands as a different user.

Both machines are Ubuntu 20.04. What could be causing the difference?

Comment: Are you executing the command as root, or as a non-privileged user? what is the `umask` in each case?

Comment: @steeldriver I am executing command as myself. I have sudo permissions on both boxes, but to expand the file, I did not use sudo. How do I check umask?

Comment: ... if you are using a bash shell, just type `umask`

Comment: On machine where it works, umask in 0022, where it fails, it's 0027.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in `man tar`, when you extract an archive using `tar` as an unprivileged user, the default behavior is to apply the invoking user's `umask` to the extracted file permissions:

```
   --no-same-permissions
          Apply  the user's umask when extracting permissions from the ar‐
          chive (default for ordinary users).
```

In particular, a umask of `0027` removes all permissions for `others`, whereas `0022` removes only write permissions.